# How to find area under curve only up until that point in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of acceleration and time values, and I need to find the velocity at that exact point in time.

The method I am using looks like this
data is a dataframe of acceleration and time values. This just gives me the area under the entire curve not the area under the curve up until that point. How do I get the area just up until that point?

```
mainData = data.assign(
z_velocity = lambda df: numpy.trapz(x=df[time], y=df[zAccel])
)
```

I also tried to create the z_velocity with just the accel * time values. Then after that is created, go back through z_velocity and assign each z_velocity a value based off of its prior value and the value of the z_velocity value placed one spot before it. This did not work.

I am relatively new to pandas and the way in which you do things is somewhat confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the area up to point t in time, you can limit the calculation by using only the first t rows of the dataframe:

```
velocity_at_t = numpy.trapz(x=df[time][:t], y=df[zAccel][:t])
```

Since everything is done in discrete time steps and `velocity(t+1) = velocity(t) + acceleration(t)`, there is an easier way to get the velocities at each timestep. If the initial velocity is 0, then we can set

```
df["velocity"] = df.zAccel.cumsum() - df.zAccel[0]
```

After running that you can verify that up to each time step, you have

```
all(df["velocity"] == [numpy.trapz(x=df.time[:t+1], y=df.zAccel[:t+1]) for t in range(len(df))])
```